# PySpark split rows and convert to RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD in which each element is having the following format

```
['979500797', ' 979500797,260973244733,2014-05-0402:05:12,645/01/105/9931,78,645/01/105/9931,a1,forward;979500797,260972593713,2014-05-0407:05:04,645/01/105/9931,22,645/01/105/863,a4,forward']
```

I want to transform it to another RDD such that key is the same i.e. 979500797 but the value is result of splitting on ';' . In other words the final output should be

```
[
   ['979500797', ' 979500797,260973244733,2014-05-0402:05:12,645/01/105/9931,78,645/01/105/9931,a1,forward']
   ['979500797','979500797,260972593713,2014-05-0407:05:04,645/01/105/9931,22,645/01/105/863,a4,forward']
]
```

I have been trying to use map like this

```
df_feat3 = df_feat2.map(lambda (x, y):(x, y.split(';')))
```

but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need here is a `flatMap`. `flatMap` takes function that returns sequence and concatenates the results.

```
df_feat3 = df_feat2.flatMap(lambda (x, y): ((x, v) for v in y.split(';')))
```

On a side note I would avoid using tuple parameters. It is a cool feature but it is no longer available in Python 3. See [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)